# What do 'Main User' and 'Meta User' mean?

Tags: support

I find the word 'meta user' in my profile section of English Language & Usage site and 'main user' in meta.english.stackexchange site. What do 'main user' and 'meta user' mean?

Answer (score 7):

Clicking on `main user` takes you to your user profile on the main site, while clicking on `meta user` takes you to that on the meta site.

Update: `main user` has been relabelled as `parent user`.

Comment: This does not explain the difference between the two.